# Game object lies down when I put NavmeshAgent as component in avocado-bone

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and also new to stack overflow so sorry in advance for lack of information I provide. I have been working on this personal unity project. here is the problem. I'm making avocado shaped basic wandering ai in my project which simply wanders around the map. I have avocado-bone prefab in my project imported as Fbx file .[avocado prefab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjkaB.png) When I run my project without Nav Mesh Agent in as component, avocado-bone stands as I intended. [This is avocado-bone object is supposed to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCUfM.jpg) However, When I put Nav Mesh Agent in as component, avocado-bone object lies down and it is problem. [This is avocado-bone with Nav Mesh Agent component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnPsZ.jpg)

Comment: depends a lot, by the look of it the default position is lying down, if so, it expects to be that, if its not, it can be becasue the pivot is up higher and the target is y 0, so pulls it down..

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by making empty parent objects and put my avocado object in it!

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure but maybe that's because the forward vector (the blue vector) is used by the navmeshagent so the navmeshagent align this blue vector with the direction of your avocado, while to be standed up, it must needed to be upward. Try to create a parent without rotation for your avocado (who will have his blue vector horizontaly), who will contains the navmeshagent as component to see if it resolves your problem